# Element inside a website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm finally "done" with my small prototype for an element inside my website. I'm just a learner in the jQuery code and that reflects in my code. It's bloated, a lot of functions do the same thing, but for a red or green button which results in this kind of code.

```
$('.submenu').on('click','.rood',function() {
    $(this).closest('.container_vragen').fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).closest('.container_vragen').css({overflow : 'hidden', color : 'red'});
        $(this).closest('.container_vragen').appendTo("#niet_geregeld");
        $(this).closest('.container_vragen').fadeIn(400);
    });
});

$('.submenu').on('click','.groen',function() {
    $(this).closest('.container_vragen').fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).closest('.container_vragen').css({overflow : 'hidden', color : 'green'});
        $(this).closest('.container_vragen').appendTo("#geregeld");
        $(this).closest('.container_vragen').fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

As you can see most of the functions are the same, only the color and the `.appedTo` id changes. What's the best way to merge this code? I'm thinking there needs to be an `if` statement which filters what button is clicked. But I can't figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function.

```
function doStuff(obj, c) {
  obj.css({overflow: 'hidden', color: c}).fadeIn(400);
}
```

Then call it

```
$('#submenu').click(function () {
  doStuff($('#geregeld'), 'green');
});
```

(simplified example)

Feel free to mess around: http://jsfiddle.net/rQFHt/

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but it's not working. If I use this code the click action on .groen is not calling the doStuff function.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma : updated :)

Answer (score 1):

You should think about chaining, to avoid repeating some class names :

```js
function doAnimation($element, $destElement, animationColor) {
    var $container_vragen = $element.closest('.container_vragen');
    $container_vragen.fadeOut(400, function() {
        $container_vragen.css({
                overflow : 'hidden',
                color : animationColor
            })
            .appendTo($destElement)
            .fadeIn(400);
    });
}

var $niet_geregeld = $('#niet_geregeld');
var $geregeld = $('#geregeld');

$('.submenu')
.on('click','.rood',function() {
    doAnimation($(this), $niet_geregeld,'red');
})
.on('click','.groen',function() {
    doAnimation($(this), $geregeld,'green');
});
```

I think preselecting `#geregeld` and `#niet_geregeld` is better for performances.

You should rename the `doAnimation` function to its real purpose, like `animateSorting` or `animateForThatPurpose`

Answer (score 1):

Store your options separately, then loop over them:

```
var $submenu = $('.submenu');
var map = {
    'rood': {
        color: 'red',
        appendTo: 'niet_geregeld'
    },
    'groen': {
        color: 'green',
        appendTo: 'geregeld'
    }
};

$.each(map, function (elClass, options) {
    $submenu.on('click', '.' + elClass, function () {

        var $container = $(this).closest('.container_vragen');

        $container.fadeOut(400, function() {
            $container
                .css({overflow : 'hidden', color : options.color})
                .appendTo("#" + options.appendTo)
                .fadeIn(400);
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two like this

```
$('.submenu').on('click', '.groen,.rood', function () {
  var $el = $(this);
  var red = $el.is('.rood'); // is this element .rood
  $el.closest('.container_vragen').css({
    overflow: 'hidden',
    color: red ? 'red' : 'green' // if it's .rood make it red.. else make green
  })
    .appendTo(red ? "#niet_geregeld" : "#geregeld") // if .rood appendto #niet_geregeld else append to #geregeld
    .fadeIn(400)
});
```

and use chaining so you don't have to keep querying the dom for the element.